# Build URL in views dependent on $_GET parameters in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have a project, where the user can filter clothing by multiple things like: color, size, price, etc.

At the moment, the user selects a color, size or price range and then via JavaScript the form gets submitted automatically. The URL then looks something like this

`http://example.com/search?color=red&size=L&price=10-50`

Now, I want to have another URL on that site, to refresh the results (which takes a bit longer, so I'll fire an Event and won't let the user wait).

The problem I'm having is to build this link. I feel like it would be stupied, to check for every `$_GET`-parameter if its set and build the URL accordingly. Is there somehow a way in Laravel to quickly build a link, that takes the current parameters and simply adds another param to it?

So in the end, the URL should look like

`http://example.com/search?color=red&size=L&price=10-50&refresh`

without programming much logic.

Comment: Well I think you should use human URL's but I will be giving answer to this ones too.

Answer (score 0):

To get value from the user and as you said

> without programming much logic.

you can get it using this way:

```
public function getValuesAndReturnView(Request $request)
{
    $color = $request->get('color');
    $size = $request->get('size');
    $price = $request->get('price');

    // Your programming logic

   return view('that.view', compact('YOUR_VARIABLES'));
}
```

Comment: Hi, that's not what I meant. It's not about returning data. That's something I'm already doing. It's more about the URL that I need to be built with the parameters without doing too much logic

Comment: Is your question about JS

Comment: No, it's about PHP. I want to build an URL with all the $_GET parameters I had before.

Comment: I'm sorry, your question is not clear to me but may be it's about storing the last values of `$_GET` variable